# Convert undirected graph to directed graph such that the indegree of each vertex is at least 2

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

For an undirected graph G if possible I want to convert G to a directed graph such that in the directed graph each vertex must have an indegree of at least 2.

I worked out that for it to be possible the amount of edges will need be at least 2|V| therefore will only be possible from at least 5 vertexs.
I also worked out that each vertex will be in a cycle with at least two other vertex,
but I tried using a modification of N/F but can't seem to think of an algorithm that can actually do the conversion (if possible).

Any help / guidance will be appreciated

Comment: How much is known about the vertex degrees? If no vertex has degree 3, you can do this by finding an Eulerian cycle (possible with dummy edges/vertices added), as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361433/orientation-of-edges-on-graphs-with-vertex-degree-constraints). With enough degree-3 vertices though, it seems like a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given an undirected, unweighted graph with n vertices and m edges, you can decide whether an orientation with minimum indegree at least 2 exists (and find it, if so) in `O(m^3)` time. If there are no vertices of degree 3, you can sometimes do this fairly simply in `O(m)` time.

If v is a vertex of degree 1, the task is impossible. If v has degree 2, both its edges must be out-edges, so we can delete 'v' from our graph for now. We do this operation repeatedly based on the new degrees; it's possible that we end up with new degree-3 vertices, but we can now assume all vertices have degree >= 3.

If all vertices are degree 4 or greater, the orientation must exist, and you can use a standard Eulerian circuit algorithm (available in many standard graph libraries) as described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361433/orientation-of-edges-on-graphs-with-vertex-degree-constraints). You may need to modify the graph first: Eulerian circuits only exist if all vertex degrees are even. There are always an even number of odd degree vertices: match them up in pairs in any way, adding an edge for each pair. Orienting the edges on the original graph based on the circuit gives a solution for your problem.

For graphs with degree-3 vertices, you can combine a standard algorithm with a nonstandard one. The standard algorithm is maximum-cardinality matching for general graphs, usually the 'Blossom algorithm', which can be found in standard graph libraries. The non-standard (i.e., probably not found in your graph library) algorithm is found in the paper [On finding orientations with the fewest number of vertices with small out-degree](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X15002292), which reduces the problem of 'Find an orientation with the fewest outdegree-less-than-2 vertices' to the problem of finding a maximum matching in a graph with `O(m)` vertices. The algorithm is quite short, and simpler since our graph has minimum degree 3. This solves your problem for fewest-indegrees-less-than-2 after you flip all edge directions.